# How to output values in hash inside JavaScript array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, each

I have a Ruby array of hashes like so:

```
[{:tour_no=>1, :occupied=>143, :signs_of_life=>133, :unoccupied=>166, :unusable=>136},
 {:tour_no=>2, :occupied=>145, :signs_of_life=>171, :unoccupied=>166, :unusable=>136}]
```

I want to output the values of `:tour_no` inside a JavaScript array to use a charting library.

Here's what I've tried by embedding some Ruby code into my HAML template:

```
categoryAxis: {
      categories: [#{occupancy_by_tour.each do |tour| tour[:tour_no] end}], 
      majorGridLines: {
          visible: false
      }
  },
```

What I want (in JavaScript):

```
categoryAxis: {
    categories: [1, 2], // Set the tour counts for a survey here.
    majorGridLines: {
        visible: false
    }
}
```

What I'm currently getting:

```
categoryAxis: {
    categories: [[{:tour_no=>1, :occupied=>143, :signs_of_life=>133, :unoccupied=>166, :unusable=>136}, {:tour_no=>2, :occupied=>145, :signs_of_life=>171, :unoccupied=>117, :unusable=>145}, {:tour_no=>3, :occupied=>136, :signs_of_life=>147, :unoccupied=>152, :unusable=>143}, {:tour_no=>4, :occupied=>141, :signs_of_life=>138, :unoccupied=>128, :unusable=>171}, {:tour_no=>5, :occupied=>150, :signs_of_life=>131, :unoccupied=>149, :unusable=>148}, {:tour_no=>6, :occupied=>137, :signs_of_life=>128, :unoccupied=>163, :unusable=>150}]],
    majorGridLines: {
        visible: false
    }

}
```

Why is the `each` block outputting the entire hash content in the JavaScript array?

Comment: That's not a hash, it's an array of hashes.

Comment: @thetimman: You're right. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map) function to return each value in the block to the template:

```
categoryAxis: {
    categories: #{occupancy_by_tour.map {|tour| tour[:tour_no]}},
    majorGridLines: {
        visible: false
    }
},
```